# TypeError: exports.property is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, module.exports

I am getting error while importing a function defined in a different js file.

util.js

```
exports.fn1 = () => {
  return "fn1";
}
exports.fn2 = () => {
  return "fn2";
}
```

index.js

```
const {fn1, fn2} = require('./util.js');
const fn0 = () => {
  const ret = fn1();
}
fn0();
```

When I run it, it gives the following error.

> TypeError: fn1 is not a function

I am new to javascript and nodejs.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the path to util.js is correct?

Comment: Oh. While checking it again, I realized the path was not correct.
It has been fixed now. Thanks  @tomerpacific :)